# How to Search for Addresses using Postal Codes

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, geocoding

I am using the `google_maps_webservice` package to fetch geocoding data from Google Maps Web Services.

I want to get the list of addresses, attached to a postal code.

Here's a small snippet of code that demonstrates that:

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';

final _places =
    GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: '<API-Key>');

void main() async {
  // This is a valid British postal code.
  final postalCode = 'WC2N 5DU';

  final response = await _places.autocomplete(
    postalCode,
    components: [
      Component(Component.postalCode, postalCode),
      Component(Component.country, 'GB'),
    ],
    location: Location(51.50721, -0.12827),
  );

  if (response.isOkay) {
    for (Prediction prediction in response.predictions) {
      print(prediction.description);
    }
  } else {
    print(response.status);
  }
}
```

I get an `INVALID_REQUEST` status message.

From the [Google Maps Geocoding docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes)

> `"INVALID_REQUEST"` generally indicates that the query `(address, components or latlng)` is missing.

The `components`, `latlng` arguments are passed to the API, but I need it to return the address, associated with the postal code.

Comment: You want to get all addresses within the postal code? What does the output you want look like?

Comment: @AlexCollette, If `response.isOkay` is `true`, I should get a `List<Prediction>` object, each `Prediction` object has a `description`, which contains the human-readable address string.

Comment: But you want to get every listed address within a postal code? Im not sure that the Geocoding API is built to do that.

Comment: Not necessarily every listed addresses, but it should return something, that shows that the postal code is valid not an `INVALID REQUEST` status. For example, this what I get when I pass the postal code to the Geocode.xyz API. http://geocode.xyz/?locate=WC2N%205DU&json=1

Answer (score 0):

Running a [reverse geocoding request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding) to fetch addresses using postal/zip code is possible, but your request needs to have the device's `latlng` (latitude, longitude). Otherwise, it'll return an "Invalid Request" error due to the missing [required parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#reverse-requests).